# My method isn't working although no error messages are shown

Tags: java, for-loop, local-variables

I need to write a method that needs to output a certain string an amount of times that equals to a variable in the main class. I wrote it with the for loop but it isn't outputting anything nor is it showing any errors. (method must contain local variable)
`public class main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFirstTry date1, date2;
    date1 = new DateFirstTry();
    date2 = new DateFirstTry();

    // Date1 declaration
    date1.month = "December";
    date1.day = 31;
    date1.year = 2012;

// Date2 declaration
    date2.month = "July";
    date2.day = 4;
    date2.year = 1776;

// Assigment
    date2.happyGreetings();
```

```
public class DateFirstTry {
    public String month;
    public int day;
    public int year; //a four digit number.
    public void writeOutput() {
        System.out.println(month + " " + day + ", " + year);
    
    }
    public void makeItNewYears() {
        this.month = "January";
        this.day = 1;
    }

    public void happyGreetings() {
        for (int i = 0; i==this.day; i++ ) {
            System.out.println("Happy Greetings!");
        }
    }
    public void getNextYear() {
    
        System.out.println(this.year + 1);
    }
    
    public void yellIfNewYears() {
        if (month.equals("January") && day == 1)
            System.out.println("Hurray!");
    else 
        System.out.println("Its not new year!");
    }
}
```

I tried to create a do-while-loop but I couldn't complete it, and I tried some minor adjustments to the for loop, but none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a mistake in loop condition. It will be executed while i == this.day. In this case 'day' equals 4 and 'i' equals 0. So, this condition is always false and loop body is never executed

```
    for (int i = 0; i==this.day; i++ ) {
        System.out.println("Happy Greetings!");
    }
```

If you want loop to be executed as many times as value in 'this.day', then you should write it like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < this.day; i++) {
        System.out.println("Happy Greetings!");
    }
```

Comment: "It will be executed until i == this.day" - no, it will be executed *while* `i == this.day` is true. (The rest of the paragraph is written correctly.)

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for your attentiveness! I have edited it